# JTree add child to child to child etc

Tags: java, tree, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

i have a problem with my first jtree :-/

i have a list of nodes, like this:

```
List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> allNodes = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
```

and now i have to create a tree

if i loop over the nodes and create my tree, it looks like

```
-0
---1
-----2
-------3
-------4
-------5
```

...but i need this structure:

```
-0 (root)
---1 (child)
-----2 (child.child)
-------3 (child.child.child)
---------4 (...)
-----------5 (etc.)
```

what am i suppose to do at this point?
any idea would be helpful. i tried many different ways, without success...

Comment: Post your code - how you are doing currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at Recursion:

```
void addNode(Node parent, Node child, List<Node> nodes){
    parent.add(child);
    if(nodes.length > 1){
        nodes.remove(child);
        addNode(child, nodes[0],nodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answer is solving your Question, please mark it as solved.